# Wordpress Media Manager 3.5 - default link to

Tags: media, media-library

Media Manager once again.
This time I'm looking for a simple hack/hook/filter to change default "Attachment Display Settings" from media manager. The option is "Link To" that is default set to "Media File" and I would like to force it for all users to be default set to "none".

[image: Media Manager Screen]

If there is no way to do it with hook/filter (media-template.php lines 282 - 306) - is there a way to attach jQuery file to Media Manager and use it to force change option after Media Manager is loaded?

Comment: As far as I can understand, the only way to do it is to use jQuery... media-template.php lines 282 - 306 - sadly "selected" is hardcoded there with no hook/filter/anything to do it.
So any ideas about adding aditional jQuery file to Media Manager with changing default option would be also a good (if not only) solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do what you want by overriding appropriate Backbone view, which is responsible for rendering attachments display settings form.

**plugin.php**

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'wpse8170_media_popup_init' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse8170_media_popup_init' );
function wpse8170_media_popup_init() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse8170-media-manager', plugins_url( '/js/media.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'media-editor' ) );
}
```

**media.js**

```
(function() {
    var _AttachmentDisplay = wp.media.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay;
    wp.media.view.Settings.AttachmentDisplay = _AttachmentDisplay.extend({
        render: function() {
            _AttachmentDisplay.prototype.render.apply(this, arguments);
            this.$el.find('select.link-to').val('none');
            this.model.set('link', 'none');
            this.updateLinkTo();
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: This is almost working solution... But when You insert image into post, it still gets inserted with anchor around it :(. Perhaps some kind of "force change" of this parameter (I dont know backbone at all :( ) would do the trick?

Comment: @MarcinBobowski I have updated my JS snippet and it works fine now. Check it out!

Comment: Yep, this is it :). I was so close to answer - model.set was the only thing that Was missing in my tries (updateLinkTo i have already fugured out). Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I believe this answer is better suited now, as WordPress does now allow you to hook into this.

The default image size, align and "link to" properties for inserting an image are set through the options `image_default_size`, `image_default_link_type` and `image_default_align`, respectively. You can change this beahviour in a couple of ways:

- In `/wp-admin/options.php`
- Directly in the options table in the database
- Through `update_option( 'default_image_link_type', 'none' )`
- By hooking into the `pre_option_[option]` filter

You can hook into the `pre_option_[option]` filter like this:

```
function wpse151868_image_default_link_type( $value ) {
    return 'none';
}

add_filter( 'pre_option_image_default_link_type', 'wpse151868_image_default_link_type' );
```

Comment: Unfortunately at least on my sites, setting `image_default_link_type` to 'none' does not change the defaults for users who were already defaulting to 'Attachment Page', so the option isn't actually global.