# add_action on a specific page

Tags: actions

I found this script [Wordpress Media Manager 3.5 - default link to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87357/wordpress-media-manager-3-5-default-link-to?rq=1)

and it works fine for me. But my problem is, that I have a custom wp_editor on the front end where I want it to work, but I can't find a way to activate it on this site..

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'load-post.php', 'wpse8170_media_popup_init' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse8170_media_popup_init' );
```

which works fine in the wp backend media manager, but not in my custom wp_editor.

The URL to the wp_editor is: `http://localhost/website.com/visitenkarten-setup/`

And the page id is 360..

Do you have any idea how I could use the add_action on this page? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your theme's *functions.php* file, or the like:

```
add_action( 'your-custom-action', 'wpse8170_media_popup_init' );
```

In the page template used for the page in question:

```
do_action( 'your-custom-action' );
```